# Given a number, find which numbers below it divide it using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I can't seem to figure this one out. I need to count how many numbers below a given number in which it is divisible.

Here is what I've tried:

```
public int testing(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        System.out.println("zero");
        return x;
    }
    else if ((x % (x-1)) == 0) {
        System.out.println("does this work?");
        x--;
    }

    return testing(x-1);
}
```

That doesn't work and I don't know where to go from here. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why are you using recursion here?

Comment: I could see using recursion for prime factorization, but to see what numbers divide yours, that's probably not the best / easiest route.

Comment: `x % (x-1)` will never be `0`. It will be always `1`. Anyway, you are changing the number that you are testing at each recursion...

Comment: @chrylis It's for an assignment. I understand recursion, but this is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Do you need to count how *many* numbers, or count *which* numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is wrong:

```
 public int testing(int x) {
```

If you want to make it recursive, you need to pass both the number to test and the number that you are currently checking. The first one will not change through the recursion, the second one will decrement. You cannot do what you express with only one parameter (unless you use a global variable).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a task that should be solved with recursion.

If you MUST use recursion, the simplest way to do it is to have a second parameter, which is essentially an "I have checked until this number". Then you can increase/decrease this (depending on if you start at 0 or the initial number) and call the recursive on that.

Thing is, Java isn't a functional language, so doing all this is actually kind of dumb, so whoever gave you this exercise probably needs a bop on the head.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your expression `x % (x - 1)` is using the "current" value of `x`, which decrements on every call to the recursive function. Your condition will be false all the way down to `2 % (2 - 1)`.

Using a `for` loop is a much better way to handle this task (and look at the Sieve of Eratosthenes), but if you really have to use recursion (for homework), you'll need to pass in the original value being factored as well as the current value being tried.

Comment: Understood. I'll make some necessary changes and will report back.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your algorithm.  Notice the recursion only ends when x == 0, meaning that your function will always return 0 (if it returns at all).

In addition, your algorithm doesn't seem to make any sense.  You are basically trying to find all factors of a number, but there's only one parameter, x.

Try to make meaningful names for your variables and the logic will be easier to read/follow.

```
public int countFactors(int number, int factorToTest, int numFactors)
{
  if (factorToTest == 0) // now you are done
    return numFactors;
  else
    // check if factorToTest is a factor of number
    // adjust the values appropriately and recurse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use recursion here. Here's a non-recursive solution:

```
public int testing(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

BTW, you should probably call this something other than `testing`.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
private static int getFactorCount(int num) {
    return getFactorCount(num, num - 1);
}

private static int getFactorCount(int num, int factor) {
    return factor == 0 ? 0 : (num % factor == 0 ? 1 : 0)
            + getFactorCount(num, factor - 1);
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getFactorCount(20)); // gives 5
    System.out.println(getFactorCount(30)); // gives 7
}
```